Keep expanded sections open while loading the next page
Metismenue allows a proper opening and expanding on a page. When I reload or call another page I lose all states and the menu is reset.
Target:
When I open a new page by link I want that the menu shall be opened at the same level as I left it with the page before e.g. I have a main point A and three subpoints A.1 A.2 A.3 and click on A.3 which opens a new page by link I want to pass a kind of parameter like in a session or by URL so that the following page knows which sections to open and which point to highlight.
I am fine with URL / Session etc. but I have no idea how to tell metismenu a kind of parameter what to display e.g. giving it an ID for every point and set this ID to active?
Any hint is highly appreciated and please on a very simple level as I am not firm in Javascript.
// EDIT //
I share here a snip of the menu code of the HTML page. The metismenu is kind of black box to me:
 <div class="sidebar_list">
        <div class="tab-content" id="main-menu">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Home-icon">
                <nav id="left-sidebar-nav" class="sidebar-nav sidebar-scroll">
                    <ul class="metismenu">
                        <li class=// setting 'active' works and marks the link active //><a href=// link to a new page, handing over session parameter or get-parameter for menue on next page //><i class="icon-speedometer"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                        <li class=// here 'active' does not work - the link is not highlighted - I guess it depends on the following <ul> //>
                            <a href=// link to another page where I can handover parameters for the state of the menu//> <i class="fa-solid fa-clipboard-question"></i><span>Request a Quote</span></a>
                            <ul id="metismenu">
                                <li class=// 'active' works here and highlights the link //><a href=// link to another page where I can send parameters for the menu //>Unit</a></li>
                                <li><a href=// some link //>Screens</a></li>
                                <li><a href=// some link //>Spare Parts</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

I am not sure how to define an ID or the like and add it to the HTML code so that when I use a GET URL like 'index.php?activeMenuPoint=x' to load the next page I can tell the menu which link to highlight and what menu to expand (in case its a menu option with sub points).
So I need an example where I have to change maybe JS and HTML to find a way to manipulate the menu on the next loaded page to show what the user has clicked on the page before (same expanded menu area and highlights).
EDIT II
I wondered if my bought template might be the problem so I checked for an example and found this:


    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/metismenu"></script>

<script>

$(function() {
  $('#menu').metisMenu({
    toggle: false // disable the auto collapse. Default: true.
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <aside class="sidebar">
        <nav class="sidebar-nav">
          <ul class="metismenu" id="menu">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="sidebar-nav-item-icon fa fa-github fa-lg"></span>
                <span class="sidebar-nav-item">metisMenu</span>
                <span class="fa arrow"></span>
              </a>
              <ul aria-expanded="true">
                <li>
                  <a href="https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu">
                    <span class="sidebar-nav-item-icon fa fa-code-fork"></span> Fork
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu">
                    <span class="sidebar-nav-item-icon fa fa-star"></span> Star
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu/issues">
                    <span class="sidebar-nav-item-icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></span> Issues
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu 0 <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul aria-expanded="false">
                <li><a href="#">item 0.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 0.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://onokumus.com">onokumus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 0.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1 <span class="glyphicon arrow"></span></a>
              <ul aria-expanded="false">
                <li><a href="#">item 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 1.2</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1.3 <span class="fa plus-times"></span></a>
                  <ul aria-expanded="false">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.3.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.3.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.3.4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">item 1.4</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1.5 <span class="fa plus-minus"></span></a>
                  <ul aria-expanded="false">
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.5.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.5.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.5.3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 1.5.4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2 <span class="glyphicon arrow"></span></a>
              <ul aria-expanded="false">
                <li><a href="#">item 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item 2.4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>



Calling the page all menues are closed. I'd expected at least the ones with "aria-expanded="true"" should have been expanded?

Please visit [ask]

sessionStorage or localStorage

Please add the menu html with real links so that we can suggest to you what is the appropriate way to achieve your goal. It's called creating a minimal reproducible example

See: metismenu events - listen for show.metisMenu and hide.metisMenu and store the current menu status in sessionStorage/localStorage.  Restore on load.

Thank you all for the hints to session, I was thinking the same, but I miss an example how to transfer the metismenu events (in JS) to my session storage system in PHP, I am a JS noob, sorry. And I miss an HTML example how to change the html code maybe with ID or CLASS taken from the storage. If you could point me here to an example or a fiddle - would be awesome, thanks.

I added some more code with EDIT II and in the end the question is: What do I have to add to the html code to make an element expand?  "aria-expanded="true" seems not to be the answer - see fiddle above with original code from metismenus without changes.
